# SQL explain plan shows very time-consuming FETCH operation

Tags: sql, join, indexing, db2

I'm working on some queries for a landing page that are assembled based on user selection of multiple values and fires them off to a DB2 database. I'm trying to tune them up to be as fast as possible with some good results. However, there are a couple of queries that have some pretty ugly execution times, as in 10s or so. I've been poring over the explain plan and have seen something rather odd.

For starters, these queries are pretty straightforward. There are several inner joins, several left joins, and a few filter conditions. They are joining some pretty huge tables (some have ~2.7 million rows) and returning some pretty beefy datasets (Up to 30k rows or so, maybe 15 or so columns). The thing is, in checking the explain plan, I've seen a pretty odd occurrence. It's a FETCH operation taking 1/3 to 1/2 of the query cost. This FETCH is related to the following join:

```
SELECT ...
FROM A
JOIN B
ON B.ID1 = A.ID1
AND B.ID2 = A.ID2
WHERE
B.FIELD IN (:parameter --No more than four strings in here)
```

A.ID1 and 2 are the primary key for A, but are not unique in B. B.FIELD is contains perhaps a dozen different string values overall, but the table is about 2.7 million rows. What I'm seeing is a FETCH operation on B that contains a RIDSCN, which itself contains one sort operation for each parameter in the B.FIELD IN clause, each sort containing an index scan on B. What's alarming is how much time the FETCH operation is eating, especially considering it's one of about a dozen joins.

I've been digging at the indexes and have a few theories, but I'm not certain where the issue lies and I cannot apply any indexes myself, only request them, so it's a bit of a pain. A is indexed on ID1 and ID2. B is also indexed on ID1 and ID2. There is a separate index that is being used for B.FIELD (that also contains a few other fields within B) within those SORT operations. However, B does not have an index on ID1, ID2, FIELD specifically. Would creating this index potentially reduce the times I'm seeing in that FETCH operation? I'm not entirely certain that this is due to the lack of a proper index or simply the size of the table and nature of the data in the column. I've requested runstats on a few tables and to see if they'd benefit from a reorg, but failing that, I'm hoping that some folks may be able to shed some light. I'm still a bit new to the application and nuances of indexes.

EDIT: Here's the relevant portion of the explain plan. It's probably worth noting that this is one of the first operations in the explain plan tree (as in after a series of NLJOIN, HSJOIN, etc):

```
SCHEMA.B  FETCH                            35.1 %    177046.0625        
    RIDSCN                                   0.0 %     5716.63037109375   
        SORT                                   0.0 %     5257.94189453125   
            B.INDEX  IXSCAN                      1.0 %     5018.35009765625   
        SORT                                   0.0 %     385.5107116699219  
            B.INDEX  IXSCAN                      0.1 %     374.5053405761719  
        SORT                                   0.0 %     50.442073822021484 
            B.INDEX  IXSCAN                      0.0 %     50.34944152832031  
        SORT                                   0.0 %     22.738037109375    
            B.INDEX  IXSCAN                      0.0 %     22.73009490966797
```

The thing is, I have some other queries that don't show this kind of cost on an IN clause, even when returning thousands of rows. Using a third of the query cost for one join seems excessive. Like I said before, perhaps it has more to do with this particular table or even the additional joins, but I'd really like to find a way to chop that number down.

Comment: *"There is a separate index that is being used for B.FIELD (that also contains a few other fields within B)"* Is B.FIELD the first column in that separate index? If it's not, the index probably won't be used when evaluating `B.FIELD IN (...)`.

Comment: It is the first field within that index, followed by two ID fields that serve as the primary key for B, although they are not used in this query.

Comment: Can you edit your question, and paste the output of EXPLAIN? I think the sort operations are normal for an IN predicate in DB2. (Sorting row identifiers makes I/O more efficient.)

Comment: How fast does this query execute: `select id1, id2 from B where FIELD in ( <your list > ) ` ?  And how many rows are returned?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this should count as an answer, but there are at least two other equivalent ways to express your intent.

```
WHERE B.FIELD = :param1 OR B.FIELD = :param2 ...

SELECT ...
WHERE B.FIELD = :param1
UNION ALL
SELECT ...
WHERE B.FIELD = :param2
...
```

I've kind of lost touch with the DB2 query optimizer over the years. It might treat these logically equivalent statements differently. That *might* not be a good thing. In the olden days, at least one product regarded it as a bug if the query optimizer generated two different execution plans for two logically equivalent queries. (Rdb? Ingres? Can't recall.)

I don't particularly like to game the optimizer that way. What performs well with an IN predicate today might be crippled by next month's updates.

As far as the composition of the indexes, this is something that I'd expect developers to be able to do as a regular part of their work. If your employer won't give you a scratch dbms to work with, then you can consider these alternatives.  (I'm not suggesting you do anything that's against your employer's policies. That's a fast way to get fired.)

- Lobby [sqlfiddle.com](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) to add support for DB2.
- Set up a computer that's not connected to your network, and run [DB2 Express-C](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express-c/download.html) on it for testing.
- Set up a computer at home, run DB2 Express-C on it, and just do testing at home.
- Set up a computer at home, set up SSH or VPN access to it, and connect to it from your work computer.

Don't move company data outside the company.

If you can't work around issues like creating indexes, go with the slow, officially sanctioned request to your DBAs.